# Canonical way to free string passed back from a c function in cffi?

Tags: python, cffi

```
ffi = FFI()
C = ffi.dlopen("mycffi.so")


ffi.cdef("""
char* foo(T *t);
void free_string(char *s);
""")

def get_foo(x):
    cdata = C.foo(x)
    s = ffi.string(cdata)
    ret = s[:]
    C.free_string(cdata)
    return ret
```

If I pass a `char *` from c function to python, python should free the memory. However, how should I do that?

My current workaround is to copy the string in python, and then free the string in C immediately. Hence Python can take care of the memory used by `ret` automatically.

What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I don't need to copy `s`, `s` is already a copy of `cdata`

```
def get_foo(x):
    cdata = C.foo(x)
    s = ffi.string(cdata)
    C.free_string(cdata)
    return s
```